# Having trouble calculating select dropbox options together

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build a simple site that will multiply three numbers from select drop boxes together. However my code only displays the number 1 when I try to calculate. I have searched for answers several hours and have been unable to come up with any changes that work. Thanks in advance.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head> 
<title>
Test Project
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />

</head>
<meta charset="utf-8" /> </meta>
<body>

<div id="div_1" align="center"

    <header id="top_header">
        <h1>Test Project</h1> 
    </header>


</div>

<div align="center">








<select id="Section1">
    <option value="1"> 1</option>
    <option value="2"> 2</option>
    <option value="3"> 3</option>
    <option value="4"> 4</option>
    <option value="5"> 5</option>
    <option value="6"> 6</option>
    <option value="7"> 7</option>
    <option value="8"> 8</option>
    <option value="9"> 9</option>
    <option value="10"> 10</option>
    </select>




<select id="Section2">
    <option value="1"> 1</option>
    <option value="2"> 2</option>
    <option value="3"> 3</option>
    <option value="4"> 4</option>
    <option value="5"> 5</option>
    <option value="6"> 6</option>
    <option value="7"> 7</option>
    <option value="8"> 8</option>
    <option value="9"> 9</option>
    <option value="10"> 10</option>
    </select>

<select id="Section3">
    <option value="1"> 1</option>
    <option value="2"> 2</option>
    <option value="3"> 3</option>
    <option value="4"> 4</option>
    <option value="5"> 5</option>
    <option value="6"> 6</option>
    <option value="7"> 7</option>
    <option value="8"> 8</option>
    <option value="9"> 9</option>
    <option value="10"> 10</option>
    </select>

    <script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("Section1").selectedIndex;
var y = document.getElementById("Section2").selectedIndex;
var z = document.getElementById("Section3").selectedIndex;
   alert(document.getElementsByTagName("Option")[x * y * z].value);
 }
</script>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>





</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression `[x * y * z].value` makes no sense. Try this instead:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("Section1").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("Section2").value;
    var z = document.getElementById("Section3").value;
    alert(x * y * z);
}
```

You can also use `selectedIndex` syntax:

```
var section1 = document.getElementById("Section1");
var x = section1.options[section1.selectedIndex].value;
// and so on..
```

But this is obviously less convenient.

Comment: That's what I am saying. I was trying to see what exactly he was doing lol

Comment: Thanks a ton. This was exactly the information I needed. I'm sorry I dont have more rep to upvote with

Answer (score 2):

This fragment `alert(document.getElementsByTagName("Option")[x * y * z]);` will take a option element from site with x*y*z index from collection of all option elements on this site.

This is what You want to get? Or You want just multiply x * y * z:

`alert(x * y * z)`

Here is a working jsfiddle for your case http://jsfiddle.net/k475jso9/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The jsfiddle link was a big help. :)